# Difference between WITH and INTO for temporary table creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

[WITH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [INTO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) seem very similar. Both create temporary tables. What differentiates them?

Comment: `WITH` doesn't create a table. It creates a temporary resultset, comparable to a subquery. `INTO` physically creates an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WITH` doesn't create a temporary table.  It allows you assign names to subqueries and then reference them in your actual query as if they were tables or views.  It allows you to do stepwise-refinement on a query in a way that would otherwise require either a series of defined table variables/temp tables, or a horrific tangle of nested subqueries.

One way to think of it is as a way of pre-defining your subqueries and then referencing them by name rather than putting the query expression in your final query.

`SELECT INTO`, on the other hand, just creates a table based on the results of the `SELECT`.